# Cannot figure out why strlen is corrupting character array in C

Tags: c, scanf, strlen

I am learning up on C and I can't figure out why this code doesn't work. I am reversing a string but strlen seems to be corrupting the input.

I know scanf can be troublesome so I tried replacing scanf with fgets (which I'm not meant to know about yet) I get exactly the same output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char inputstring[] = "";
    char outputstring[] = "";
    unsigned short int count = 0;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", inputstring);

    count = strlen(inputstring) - 1;

    printf("%s", inputstring);

    for(int i = 0;i <= count;i++)
    {
        outputstring[count-i] = inputstring[i];
    }

    printf("%s", outputstring);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and execute the code I get:

Enter a string: hello
h

so the printf displays one character and then garbage.

If I comment out the strlen line, the printf displays correctly:

Enter a string: hello
hello

Comment: `char inputstring[] = "";` this just sets aside one char of space for the null terminator and nothing else. It's going to cause undefined behavior when you try to write a string to it with `scanf("%s", inputstring);`.

Comment: @Blaze That does indeed work! I missed that. What would be best practice if I don't know the length of the string so don't want to put a length. Is that even possible?

Comment: Also you're not null terminating the reversed string, put a `outputstring[count+1] = '\0';` after the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays in C are not dynamic, and by declaring them like you do:

```
char inputstring[] = "";
char outputstring[] = "";
```

they are basically fixed size arrays of length 1.
Try declaring them with a length, e.g.

```
char inputstring[100] = "";
char outputstring[100] = "";
```

Comment: Makes sense now. Must've missed that in the content. Thanks.